# hg diff shows irrelevant changes for files in specific directory

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a situation where the command hg diff does not show the actual changes I made instead shows different changes. It's weird that it is happening for the file later I tried another file in the same directory it has the same issue. But other files in different directories do not have any issue.

Example -- There is a file like "test.php" where I added a new line with text "test", usually for other files when I do hg diff it will show + "test" but in this case, it shows irrelevant:

[image]

I have added only the word "test" and the rest of the things are not my changes.

All the permissions are the same and I have tried with "hg diff" and "hg diff -g" commands but have the same result. Appreciate it if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Can you post more specifics of what the files are, what the "real" differences are, and what hg is reporting?

Comment: There is a specific file like "test.php" where I added a new line with text "test", usually for other files when I do hg diff it will show + "test" but in this case, it shows irrelevant. Please see https://www.screencast.com/t/fLnXLvu16  in the screenshot you can see the same. I have added only the word "test" and the rest of the things are not my changes

Comment: When you say "the rest of the things" do you mean just the two backslash \\ characters?

Comment: No, I mean all the other text

Comment: I don't see any other changes in that listing. Maybe I'm missing it, its rather dense & hard to read. What other changes do you see?

Comment: Is it possible you are not reading the diff format correctly? diffs usually contain some extra lines as context which have not actually changed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format